# Python discord bot how to compare messages with a list

Tags: python, python-requests, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm making a python Discord Bot and now i'm trying to make him respond to a certain message within a list, but there are some issues, because he only respond when the message starts the text (not in the middle or end). So i want to figure out how to make him compare all the text and match with the messages list, sending a text answer.

Python 3.8.2

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext        import commands
from discord.ext.commands   import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")
phrases = ["QWACK","KWAK","AARK","KWAAAK"]

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("I'm ready!")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(phrases) in message.content:                                                    
        await message.channel.send("dhbang")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wrong1man said, `str(phrases)` is a string, so it should only respond to messages like `Lovely day, isn't it ["QWACK","KWAK","AARK","KWAAAK"]?`.
I would just like to extend wrong1man's answer by giving some code:

```
if any((phrase in message.content) for phrase in phrases):                                                    
    await message.channel.send("dhbang")
```

The above is the more concise version using [a generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). If you are a Python begginer, you may be more comfortable with a normal for loop:

```
for phrase in phrases:
    if phrase in message.content:                                                    
        await message.channel.send("dhbang")
        break
```

Comment: Oh, ty. I completely forgot to use a loop for this (was stuck to the discord library). Yes, i'm a begginer (thx for the pacience) and you guys helped me a lot.

Comment: @DearFuture You're welcome! If this answered your question, it would be helpful if you could mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i'm amazed the bot responds at all xD

str(phrases) is a string, this specific string: "["QWACK","KWAK","AARK","KWAAAK"]"

You should iterate over each word, and check if that word is in the message.

You should also take into consideration capitalization and multiple keywords appearing in one message.

Comment: I put the "str" because i tried just "phrases" but it gives an error message. How do you recommend me to write the lines?